# Decrypting an XML file

Tags: xml, encryption, aes

I have this xml file that needs to be decrypted.

Does anyone know how to decrypted something like this?

It came with a file from Daisy ebooks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dtbook SYSTEM "dtbook-2005-3.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="daisy.css" media="screen"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="daisyTransform.xsl" media="screen"?>
<EncryptedData xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
<EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/>
<CipherData>
<CipherValue> 

SomeText...

</CipherValue>
</CipherData>
</EncryptedData>
```

Thank you very much for your help,
if you need the actual text, that can be provided as well.

Comment: More important, did it come with any kind of key?

Comment: this might help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-encryption

Comment: @HenkHolterman I am afraid it did not come with a key, the device that it is installed on should have the key on it. But my mac does not.

Comment: @helb I am not exactly sure what that code means, i am very new to the coding world and even newer to encryption

Comment: Without a key you're not going to get anywhere. That would be your first problem to solve. Then you could look for a tool or create one.